SOAP request with wsse security headers with SOAP sender adapter : SAP CPI
I have a SOAP to SOAP scenario in SAP CPI. The target web service expects the request with SOAP envelope along with wsse:Security headers. This is built in the source system and sent to CPI as it is. The request coming to CPI looks something like this:

But it is currently failing at the SOAP sender adapter with the following error:

Could someone please explain what needs to be done? Currently I am not able to understand why the request is not even going into the iFlow. It simplay always fails at the sender SOAP adapter. It works when I remove the security headers from the SOAP envelope. I have set the "Service Definition" as Manual in the SOAP sender. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!
